# How to add pickup and PickupsDeliveries point in a correct way in google or tools

Tags: modeling, or-tools, vehicle-routing

Assuming we have this piece of code

```
  public class DataModel
    {
        public long[,] DistanceMatrix = {
            { 0, 548, 776, 696, 582, 274, 502, 194, 308, 194, 536, 502, 388, 354, 468, 776, 662 },
            { 548, 0, 684, 308, 194, 502, 730, 354, 696, 742, 1084, 594, 480, 674, 1016, 868, 1210 },
            { 776, 684, 0, 992, 878, 502, 274, 810, 468, 742, 400, 1278, 1164, 1130, 788, 1552, 754 },
            { 696, 308, 992, 0, 114, 650, 878, 502, 844, 890, 1232, 514, 628, 822, 1164, 560, 1358 },
            { 582, 194, 878, 114, 0, 536, 764, 388, 730, 776, 1118, 400, 514, 708, 1050, 674, 1244 },
            { 274, 502, 502, 650, 536, 0, 228, 308, 194, 240, 582, 776, 662, 628, 514, 1050, 708 },
            { 502, 730, 274, 878, 764, 228, 0, 536, 194, 468, 354, 1004, 890, 856, 514, 1278, 480 },
            { 194, 354, 810, 502, 388, 308, 536, 0, 342, 388, 730, 468, 354, 320, 662, 742, 856 },
            { 308, 696, 468, 844, 730, 194, 194, 342, 0, 274, 388, 810, 696, 662, 320, 1084, 514 },
            { 194, 742, 742, 890, 776, 240, 468, 388, 274, 0, 342, 536, 422, 388, 274, 810, 468 },
            { 536, 1084, 400, 1232, 1118, 582, 354, 730, 388, 342, 0, 878, 764, 730, 388, 1152, 354 },
            { 502, 594, 1278, 514, 400, 776, 1004, 468, 810, 536, 878, 0, 114, 308, 650, 274, 844 },
            { 388, 480, 1164, 628, 514, 662, 890, 354, 696, 422, 764, 114, 0, 194, 536, 388, 730 },
            { 354, 674, 1130, 822, 708, 628, 856, 320, 662, 388, 730, 308, 194, 0, 342, 422, 536 },
            { 468, 1016, 788, 1164, 1050, 514, 514, 662, 320, 274, 388, 650, 536, 342, 0, 764, 194 },
            { 776, 868, 1552, 560, 674, 1050, 1278, 742, 1084, 810, 1152, 274, 388, 422, 764, 0, 798 },
            { 662, 1210, 754, 1358, 1244, 708, 480, 856, 514, 468, 354, 844, 730, 536, 194, 798, 0 }
        };
        // [START pickups_deliveries]
        public int[][] PickupsDeliveries = {
            new int[] { 1, 6 }, new int[] { 2, 10 },  new int[] { 4, 3 },   new int[] { 5, 9 },
            new int[] { 7, 8 }, new int[] { 15, 11 }, new int[] { 13, 12 }, new int[] { 16, 14 }


        };
        // [END pickups_deliveries]
        public int VehicleNumber = 5;
        public int Depot = 0;
    }
```

**When I trying to add point, I am running into an exception from google or tools, So I need to know how add the point in the correct way to the PickupsDeliveries.**

Error:

Exception thrown at 0x00007FF8498DCCC7 (google-ortools-native.dll) in VRPBugFix.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF8.

The point that I addeded: new int[] {12 ,16}

Thank you all.

Comment: what is the error ? Please provide a minimal stand alone code.

Comment: Exception thrown at 0x00007FF8498DCCC7 (google-ortools-native.dll) in VRPBugFix.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF8.

The point that I addeded: new int[] {12 ,16}

Comment: you cannot visit a node twice. So a node cannot be part of 2 pickups and deliveries.

Comment: What are the rules to add new points without violating the algorithm? also If I have Lets say 10 passengers that will go from Point A To B if I can't visit node more than one , So how can we handle it? Thank you a lot for appreciating all of the effort with me.

Comment: duplicate the nodes. read the mailing lists, stack overflow. This has been asked multiple times.

Comment: If I have 2000 customers for one pickup point going to many delivery points, is duplicating the node in the distance matrix the only efficient solution, or are there alternative approaches that could be more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the distributed examples:

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/vrp_pickup_delivery.py

Comment: The above code actually from google itself.